# How to change a line in a YAML file?

Tags: python, yaml

I have a bunch of YAML files and each file has one line of code that needs to be changed. I am trying to automate it using Python, what's the best way to do this?

Right now I have a list of the files, and I plan on opening each one and finding the line needed to be changed then replacing it.

Is this possible? I can't seem to figure out how to replace the line. I know the exact line number, could that help?

Comment: use a yaml parsing library, you just need the attribute name

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the exact line number, this is quite easy - it doesn't even matter that the file is YAML if you know exactly what you need to replace it with.

I'm assuming here that all the files that need their lines changed are in the same directory, with no other YAML files. If this isn't the case then the program will require fine-tuning of course.

```
import os
line_number = 47  # Whatever the line number you're trying to replace is
replacement_line = "Whatever string you're replacing this line with"

items = os.listdir(".")  # Gets all the files & directories in the folder containing the script

for file_name in items:  # For each of these files and directories,
    if file_name.lower().endswith(".yaml"):  # check if the file is a YAML. If it is:
        with open(file_name, "w") as file:  # Safely open the file
            data = file.read()  # Read its contents
            data[line_number] = replacement_line  # Replace the line
            file.write(data)  # And save the file
```

Note that if your files are .yml rather than .yaml, then you would have to change that in the code. Additionally, if your files are too large this could cause problems as each file is loaded into memory.

If this doesn't work for you, then there are other solutions around the internet, including Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks for the input! However I am getting some errors, the data[line_number] only gives the indexed character not the line. Also, I am getting an error of "TypeError: an integer is required. I'm assuming this is because data[line_number] doesn't actually replace the line. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielShen The TypeError you are getting - can you tell me what line it's on?

Comment: Yep! its the data[line_number] = replacement_line

Comment: @GabrielShen Sorry for the 8 day wait. If it isn't fixed, could you send me what you've got on line 2 (The `line_number` one)?

Answer (score 0):

I use the [pyyaml](https://pyyaml.org/) library (`pip install pyyaml`):

It handles the full YAML syntax as shown in the example below:

- `python example`

```
import yaml

with open("data.yaml", "w+") as FILE:
    data = yaml.load(FILE)
    data.pop("token_default")
    yaml.dump(data)
```

- `data.yaml`

```
token_default: &token
  token      : !!str
  type       : # var, field, list, vector
  version    : 0.1
  namespace  : cam_tokens
  properties :
    unit   : !!seq [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    min    : !!float +inf
    max    : !!float -inf
    argPos : !!int -1
  required   :
    - unit
    - argPos

mass:
  <<: *token
  token: mass
  namespace  : cam_tokens
  properties :
    unit   : !!seq [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  required   :
    - unit
    - argPos
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the input! What is the data.pop("token_default") needed for?

Comment: Just modifying the data by removing the "token_default" entry as it is not needed after serialisation. It was merely intended to illustrate that the YAML file is parsed and produces the good old dictionary datatype internally in python.